# Why Flutter complains about 2 body parameters?

Tags: flutter, parameters, flutter-layout

In the tutorial we see two body parameters: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab
Like that:

```
              body: const Center(
22
    -           child: Text('Hello World'),
23
    +         body: Center(
24
    +           child: Text(wordPair.asPascalCase),
```

But on the dartpad.dev I have an error:
`The argument for the named parameter 'body' was already specified.`

I have this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Hello there')),
        body: const Center(
          
          child: Text('The word is'),
        ),
        body: Center(child: Text(wordPair)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet shows the changes made in the starter code. They don't coexist

[image]
If you look at the left you see the minus and plus sign.